# Trigger method in other class without new instance/static

Tags: c#

I am stuck in this phase of my project. I have 2 window classes.

```
ClassA
//This window is like a main form which can take you to Class B

ClassB
//This window is a search window that's suppose to set a static object in class A and fire a method `FillData()` in class A.
```

I can't make this method static since it will require me to change a lot of variables within it's scope to static.

How would you trigger the `FillData()` method in class A from Class B without using static ? `FillData()` is suppose to be called when i press an OK button from `classB` after search.

This is my 2nd week in the C# world :)

Comment: is Class B a dialog window open from class A and that will close when user press OK?

Comment: Couldn't you just do `ClassA.FillData();`?

Comment: @GianPaolo thanks got it solved.But there are all equally windows or forms if i may say.

Comment: @KiroYakuza from my OOP knowledge you can't access non static variables like that or can you ?

Comment: you can access non static members of a class from another class as long as the member are public. for non static member, of course, you need an instance of that class to access the public members (**of that instance**).

Comment: and in general, avoid a design that require static variable. Static variables are actually global variables (one copy of the variable in the entire program, even if they are scoped within a class). There are cases that they can be useful, passing a return value from a Dialog is not one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use the static keyword, you could simply make the instances of both classes static inside your main class. This way, you don't have to make anything static inside your classes.

```
public static ClassA Instance1 = new ClassA();
public static ClassB Instance2 = new ClassB();
```

e.g.

```
Program.Instance1.FillData();
```